# To use HAVING in SQL, JOIN and COUNT

Tags: sql

I need to show the number of salespeople who represent at least one studio, each. My studios table resembles the following:

```
Studios
-------
StudioID, Studioname, Email, SalesID
```

The Salespeople table resembles the following:

```
Salespeople
---------------
SalesID, Firstname, Lastname
```

I formulated the following query:

```
 SELECT sp.firstname, 
           sp.lastname, 
           Count(sp.salesid) AS NumberOfSalesPeople 
    FROM   salespeople sp 
           JOIN studios s 
             ON s.salesid = sp.salesid 
    HAVING Count(s.studioid) > 0;
```

However, I do not think it is completely correct. Again, the question is: show the number of salespeople who represent at least one studio each.

Comment: +1 for showing what you've tried

Comment: I don't understand the significance of the word "each" in the question. You just want all the SalesPeople with at least one corresponding entry in `Studios`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to show the **number** of salespeople who represent at least one studio, each

The answer to that requirement would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SalesId) NumberOfSalesPeople FROM Studios
```

Not sure why you've added so much additional information in the query you've formulated.